# Get the location of an user in dialogflow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I would like to know, How can i get the location of ChatBot user with DialogFlow. It is to avoid asking him and simplifying the communication.

(Sorry my english is bad)

Comment: for which platform you are creating the bot?

Comment: I use twilio for use chatbot with phone text message

Comment: There is no inherent location for a user chatting over SMS, so you will need to ask. Sai.raj's answer below should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow provides **Helpers** for that purpose.

Refer the Official Documentations which has an example of accessing user's [location](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#place_and_location)

Hope that helps!